# Trying to check if the x, y parameter in this function has been the same for quite some time, but doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So... I'm trying to check if the x, y parameter in this function below has been the same for quite some time, and if it has, the reward variable should go down... I don't know if my issue is due to the mouseX, mouseY values being numpy arrays, but...

Code:

```
def xystoreandcheck(x, y, reward):
    global mouseX
    np.append(x, mouseX)
    global mouseY
    np.append(y, mouseY)
    if len(mouseX) > 4:
        if mouseX[-1] == mouseX[-2] or mouseX[-3] == mouseX[-1]:
            reward += -10.00
            print("Actor reward is now " + str(reward) + " due to agent failing to move mouse pointer in X coords.")
    if len(mouseY) > 4:
        if mouseY[-1] == mouseY[-2] or mouseY[-3] == mouseY[-1]:
            reward += -10.00
            print("Actor reward is now " + str(reward) + " due to agent failing to move mouse pointer in Y coords.")
    return reward
```

Comment: One problem with your code is probably that `np.append` does not work in-place. You have to assign its return value, otherwise it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things that could cause your problems:

1. [`np.append()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) is not an in-place operation so you should assign its return value. Also the first parameter should be the array and the second parameter the value you want to append: `mouseX = np.append(mouseX, x)`
2. Do you want to check if the last three values are all the same? Then the `or` in the condition should be an `and`.